# How do I know if the app is installed on a device?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Is there a way to be sure if there's some application (using its package name) installed on the android device? Maybe using NDK if it makes sense.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationInfo(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: @CommonsWare is it allow to get information about another applications which are not my applications?

Comment: Yes, that is the point behind that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use something like:

```
public static boolean isAppInstalled(Context context, String appPackageName) {
    try {
        context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(appPackageName, 0);
        return true;
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```